# Can't assign HTMLDivElement to useRef<HTMLElement>

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

In my hook, I want to keep a reference to an HTML element.
The type of element might be any class inherited from `HTMLElement` like `HTMLDivElement`, `HTMLAnchorElement`, etc.

```js
const useSomething = () => {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLElement | null>(null);

  return ref;
};

const Component = () => {
  const ref = useSomething();

  return <div ref={ref} />;
};
```

Type `HTMLDivElement` is inherited from `HTMLElement`, however the code results in the following error

```
Type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLElement | null>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLDivElement> | undefined'.
  Type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLElement | null>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<HTMLDivElement>'.
    Types of property 'current' are incompatible.
      Type 'HTMLElement | null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLDivElement | null'.
        Property 'align' is missing in type 'HTMLElement' but required in type 'HTMLDivElement'.ts(2322)
```

I solved the issue by asserting the ref to `RefObject<HTMLDivElement>`

```js
<div ref={ref as RefObject<HTMLDivElement>} />;
```

But it's mandatory that people dont need to perform any additional actions on the ref in their components. The usage example must look like this

```js
<div ref={ref}/>; // no warnings
```

Is there a way to solve the issue without using the `ref as RefObject<HTMLDivElement>` in the component?

Comment: The given answer is, uhm, incorrect at least. I'd just make your hook generic to propagate the type: `const useSomething = <T extends HTMLElement>() => useRef<T>(null)` and then `const ref = useSomething<HTMLDivElement>()`.

Answer (score -1):

Well the problem is your type isn't correct in your useRef... You are allowing it to accept null as an acceptable reference type... This is not what you want... You want to still maintain what type you are expecting (not the exception - being that null). Secondly be specific, use the HTMLDivElement type if you can.

```
useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
```

instead of

```
useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
```

You may even type it as `<HTMLDivElement | HTMLElement>` but I wouldn't recommend this.
So the reason you are facing this error is because null is not an acceptible type for your reference and doesn't have the overlap (as it points out). You can read more about typing the useRef hook [here](https://linguinecode.com/post/how-to-use-react-useref-with-typescript)